# Compress 8 chars in 7 bytes

Tags: c++

I have a std::string of eight characters and an index value (int) of a drop down control. I have only 8 bytes to store all the data.

Is it possible to compress the 8 chars into 7 bytes in order to spare the eighth byte for the index value?

Comment: If all the `char`s are 1-127 ASCII, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: Not without losing info.

Comment: Supposing they're ASCII, yes. **BUT**…

Comment: (1) It depends on what's in those chars; (2) Whether or not you can fit an `int` in a single byte also depends on the range of values that the `int` can take.

Comment: What is the possible range of characters in the string?

Comment: Wait - "I have only 8 bytes to store all the data." **what**?

Comment: Why are you inventing all these complications just to save a single byte?

Comment: but why? why,why,why?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Actually I am working on an application which has a pre-defined number of bytes for saving information. I have added a drop down control and want to merge its index in these eight bytes due to the application limitation. The string contains 8 hex digits, say "36CD8F3F". Index value is either 0 or 1 so it can be stored in one byte as 0x00 or 0x01.

Comment: Well, at least this is entertaining :)

Comment: Then why not send a 4-byte uint32_t and call it good? (ok 5 bytes, but that includes your "index", whatever that is).

Comment: @WaqasDanish: 8 hex digits = **4** bytes...

Comment: Is this 8-digit hex string coming from the UI? Are there any further restrictions on the values it can take?

Comment: A `std::string` with eight characters already takes up more than a total of eight bytes. So, you already failed.

Comment: On a 32-bit system, 8 bytes is enough to store a pointer.  Then, you can store anything in those 8 bytes.

Comment: I suspect that, like many GUI controls like list items, the control has one 'auxiliary' var available for user data.  This is usually an int and, in many cases, means using a nasty cast from/to some object/struct pointer to effectively 'store more than one int'.  Ugly/nasty, yes, but often unavoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **assuming** your characters only take on values in the standard ASCII character set.

If this assumption is correct, then they only take on values 0-127 (i.e. 7-bit values).  So you only have 8 * 7 bits of information.  And you have 7 * 8 bits to store this in.  So just strip out the MSB of each char, and pack them.

---

<sub>*However, this seems like an awful lot of work just to save a single byte.  Do you really need to do this?*</sub>

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, which is why this only works if one assumes ASCII-valued characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
unsigned long long pack(const std::string& s, unsigned index)
{
    return (s[0] & 127)
         | (s[1] & 127) << 7
         | (s[2] & 127) << 14
         | (s[3] & 127) << 21
         | (s[4] & 127) << 28
         | (s[5] & 127) << 35
         | (s[6] & 127) << 42
         | (s[7] & 127) << 49
         |     index    << 56;
}
```

Comment: There's a slight problem here, UB. `s[]` returns `char` or `int` and you can't shift that by more than the number of bits in `int` minus 1.

Comment: And how to convert back to string and index value?